# giving download permission to an object in s3

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a lambda function written which creates a file named 'report.csv' every time it is run.
And as with every run the filename is same, the same file gets updated. (It was desired)

Now i want to download that file by clicking on download button.

Here is the download button:

```
<a href="https://vipauditresult.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/report.csv" download="report.csv">
    <button><Download</button>
</a>
```

But i am not able to access that file from the UI.
I think i need to set some permissions in the s3 bucket but i don't know what. Can anyone help??

Here is the lambda function code that puts report.csv in bucket:

```
s3_bucket = 'vipauditresult'
csv_buffer = StringIO()
grid_sizes.to_csv(csv_buffer, sep=",", index=False) //grid_sizes contains the csv data
s3.Object(s3_bucket, 'report.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: You want to do this only for this one specific file called `report.csv` in a bucket `vipauditresult`?

Comment: yes and also i can not give direct public permission to the file as it gets replaced with a new file with the same name every time lambda function runs.

Comment: When doing [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) api call in your lambda you can set `ACL` to `public-read` to the file. The bucket's [public acceess settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html) need to be adjusted beforehand.

Comment: how to do that?? i have put the lambda code that puts report.csv in the bucket. please see to that.

Comment: I added an answer with alternative, probably simpler way.

Comment: yeah it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to put a [bucket policy allowing public read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) for your one file:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vipauditresult/report.csv"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to add the policy is shown here:

- [How do I add an S3 Bucket policy?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html)

You also have to disable [public access settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html#block-public-access-bucket-one) for the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

i added this in the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from dwaw5cmmjauvu.cloudfront.net/",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vipauditresult/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://dwaw5cmmjauvu.cloudfront.net/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```